# Optimizing data structure using JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm building some graphs using crossfilter.js using two datasets (in CSV). This creates issues and I feel if I could figure out a way to combine the two into a single all-powerful dataset in JSON format then my issues will be resolved. The problem is, one dataset is more detailed than the other, and it's not possible for the 2nd dataset to be as granular.

The layout of each dataset:

```
ds1: recorddate -> region -> channel -> product -> revenue
ds2: recorddate -> region -> channel -> headcount

ds1 output:
recorddate  region  channel    product   revenue
1/1/2017    east    walmart    apples    10
1/1/2017    east    walmart    oranges   15

ds2 output:
recorddate  region  channel    headcount
1/1/2017    east    walmart    5
1/1/2017    east    target     7
```

- recorddate is a monthly view (1/1/2017, 2/1/2017, etc.)
- region is an area assignment (east, west)
- channel represents where a person sales (walmart, target)
- product represents the type of sale (think apples, oranges, etc.)
- their is only a single metric in each dataset; all other fields are attributes

In case it isn't clear from the datasets above, `headcount` cannot be calculated at the `product` level. So a simple join would not work (otherwise I'd do it in SQL).

Can JSON solve this problem by creating some nested objects, or perhaps a more elegant way is possible in the code? The layout needs to be able to "roll-up" to the most parent level (i.e. Calculating headcount by recorddate, revenue by channel, etc.) to satisfy all metrics being reported.

Comment: What value do you expect to be shown for `headcount` if "walmart apples" is selected?

Comment: Apples would be irrelevant for headcount and the result would be 5. Headcount represents the number of people in a channel and they each have the opportunity to sell each of the products.

Comment: Could you detail what are the "issues" encountered, please?

Comment: If I was to join the two CSVs together then the headcount value would be duplicated for every product. If I was to then sum headcount by region it will oversum by a factor of the number of products. Unless there is something I'm missing here.

Comment: Crossfilter ordinarily aggregates by row, so I don't think there is a pure crossfilter way to do this. I'm hoping @EthanJewett will pop on with some hints but it seems like you'd have to create a dimension keyed on date,region,channel, put headcount in an exterior map (js object) and then reduceSum using that object. Not horrible but a little messy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Gordon. I'm open to any and all suggestions. If that's a viable option then I will pursue it. I am, however, unfamiliar with the process you mentioned. Do you have any examples or documentation to better explain?

Comment: I'll write up an answer once I'm clear what you're trying to do. Last question, hopefully: what do you want to do with headcount? It's easy to get a total but binning headcount by any of date,region,channel might take a little more effort.

Comment: Ideally headcount will be able to be sliced by date, region, and channel. The sql output provides this info and looks like the format I laid out above.  At this time I have a bar showing total revenue by region, a pie showing revenue by channel, and will have a number display showing headcount once it's working. I'd like the reduceSum to return the appropriately sliced headcount based on the selections from the other graphs. I have the code written for a composite chart with a right axis showing headcount over time, left axis showing rev over time. But that's most likely not relevant here. TY!

Comment: Hmm, I think we'll end up aggregating up to those three columns using crossfilter, and then doing the rest by hand. I don't think crossfilter supports multi-level aggregation like this. (Although I'm still hoping @EthanJewett stops by with a better idea.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the by hand method you mentioned above? I'm hoping to wrap my head around the process that will have to be taken. Thanks for the continued attention. Paging @EthanJewett!